# No template found for UsersController#create, rendering head :no_content Completed 204 No Content in 3568ms (ActiveRecord: 46.7ms)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

i'm new in RoR, i know a little english too so i am having troubles while programming my web application.
I follow a tutorial and i try to use the code learned in other methods.

The error is the next: ***No template found for UsersController#create, rendering head :no_content Completed 204 No Content in 3568ms (ActiveRecord: 46.7ms)***

And this is code from users_controller.rb

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if params[:store_id].present?
    if @str && @str.authenticate(params[:store][:password])
      if @user.save
        log_in @user
        remember @user
        flash[:success] = "Bienvenido a take a break"
        redirect_to current_user
        # Handle a successful save.
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

I'm using Bcrypt, i hope you can help me, if you need more about te code request. I hope can understand my english.

Answer (score 0):

This action searches for either `new` template or `create` template in your `views/users` folder to render depending on the result of your conditions. Seems like you don't have one of the templates (or both).